# PHP: Automatically send a group email once I post something to my website

Tags: php, mysql, database, email

I have a function where lets say an 'admin' can post content to my website for regular users to see. Once this is done I would like to be able to send an email to anyone who is registered on my site (I have these stored in a field in my 'users' database). I am using XAMMP and MySQL but will be registering on a live host soon.

I have heard that using PHPMailer will be the best for this however my site will have a maximum of 120 users at a time therefore if I could loop through my records in my database, and call an email function each times and send to that address that would be great. I am new to PHP and have built this website using tutorials online for the most part however this really has me stumped!

I have a contact form where users can contact me however I do not know how to go about my problem above.

```
<?php
$to = 'davidforde1991@gmail.com';
$subject = 'PLACEMENT_PARTNER_CONTACT';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$message = <<<EMAIL

HI! My name is $name.

$message

From $name
Oh ya, my email is $email

EMAIL;

$header = '$email';

if($_POST){
mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
$feedback = 'Thanks for contacting PSquared! We will be in contact soon!';
}

?>

<form action="?" method="post">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="topic">Topic:</label>
                <select id = "topic">
                    <option value="Ponies">Ponies</option>
                    <option value="Mexicans">Mexicans</option>
                    <option value="Weiner">Weiner</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="message">Message:</label>
                <textarea id="message" name="message" cols="42" rows="9"></textarea>
            </li>
            <li><input type="submit" value="Submit"></li>
        </ul>
    </form>
```

I know the above code isn't relevant, but I have code in place to loop through fields in my db already if that is of help.

```
   <?php
   // Connects to the Database
   mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db("users_db") or die(mysql_error());

//checks cookies to make sure they are logged in
    if(isset($_COOKIE['username']))
    {
    $username = $_COOKIE['username'];
    $pass = $_COOKIE['pass'];
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '$username'")or   die(mysql_error());
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))
    {
        $username = $row['user_name'];
        $email = $row['user_email'];
    }
    //if the cookie has the wrong password, they are taken to the login page

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

new to php, welcome i guess!
to answer your question,
its something like this

```
function tell_eveyone_i_just_updated_my_website($additional_info){
if(empty($additional_info)/* && $additional_info!=='0'*/){$additional_info='';}
if(!is_string($additional_info)){
throw new InvalidArgumentException('if $additional_info is not empty, it must be a string!');
}
$pdoh=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=users_db;charset=utf8;','root','',array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
$pdostatementh=$pdoh->prepare("SELECT `user_name`,`user_email` FROM  `users` WHERE 1");
$pdostatementh->execute();
$row=NULL;
while(false!==($row=$pdostatementh->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))){
//$username= $row['user_name'];//
$email = $row['user_email'];
mail($email, "i just updated my website!","i just updated my website! ".$additional_info);
}

};

tell_everyone_i_just_updated_my_website("added a new article about cats");
```

and now to nitpick,

here:

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '$username'")or   die(mysql_error());
```

you are vunrable to SQL Injection attack... if som1 put their username to something like 
this: hacker'; DROP DATABASE `users`; --

they will delete your database!  (solution: mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."'") )

```
isset($_COOKIE['username'])
```

DO NOT USE THIS TO CHECK IF SOM1 IS LOGGED IN, A HACKER CAN FAKE THIS. (solution: use $_SESSION )

```
if($_POST){
```

should be

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

(reason is, if a POST request contains no actual POST data, even though it is technically a POST request, $_POST will still evaluate to false..)

next, you may want to verify that name/email/message is actually given in the POST request, or it can cause unhandled errors in your php code.. (but honestly, who reads the server error log anyway, right?...) something like

```
if(!isset($_POST['name'])){echo "malformed POST request! name missing!";/*~~*/}
```

next, DO NOT USE mysql_  API, it will removed from PHP soon, and your code will stop working in a future PHP update.  instead use PDO or MySQLi